# Castle ActiveRecord joins

Tags: castle-activerecord

I'm a new Castle ActiveRecord user, and I now find it necessary to do a select that involves a JOIN. I have no idea how to do so.

Here's my two (sample) classes:

```
[ActiveRecord("Orders")]
public class Order : ActiveRecordBase<Order>
{
   [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Identity)]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string ShipName { get; set; }
```

}

```
[ActiveRecord("Users")]
public class UserAccount : ActiveRecordBase<UserAccount>
{
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Identity)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

}

Now if I want to get all orders, along with the UserAccount.FirstName and UserAccount.LastName, how do I do it? By my reading, I need to create another class like "OrdersWithUserAccount" but I have no idea how to define it.

Thanks for helping out a noob!

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the [Castle ActiveRecord tutorial](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/gettingstarted/index.html)?

One thing I notice is that you don't have *object* relations, but *key* relations.  To use NHibernate and Castle ActiveRecord the way they're intended, your object model should have relationships *betweeen objects*.

This means that your `Order` class should have a `User` property which points to an instance of a `UserAccount`.  Your `UserAccount` class should have an `Orders` collection.  In my experience, this should usually be an `ISet<Order>`, which you initialize in the `UserAccount` constructor as a `HashedSet<Order>`.